# Transpose Noether current from $U(1)$ symmetry of the free Dirac field

Tags: conventions, fermions, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

When I read through the notes of a particle physics script there is the following identity that I don't understand
$$\left(\psi^T {\gamma^\mu}^T \bar{\psi}^T \right)^T = -\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi.$$ Where $\psi$ denotes a Dirac field.
Can someone give me a hint, how to prove this?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which notes?